# Unhiding Excel 2013 Windows when all Windows are hidden with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I think I may have found a bug in VBA for Excel 2013:
If **all the windows in Excel are hidden** the command:

```
WBk.windows(1).visible = true
```

(Where WBk is a workbook) Returns:

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.

it does work in previous versions of Excel.

The only way I can find of unhiding the hidden workbook is to add a new blank workbook, unhide the hidden workbook, then close the new, blank workbook:

```
Dim Wbk2 As Workbook

Set Wbk2 = Workbooks.Add()

WBk.Windows(1).Visible = True

Wbk2.Close (False)
```

Which strikes me as a strange thing to have to do.

Is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Many thanks in Advance!

Comment: I've just discovered that this issue is particular to the rest of the code in my excel workbook, as I can't re-create the issue. I think it may be due to Forms showing... Still any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I made some test but everything worked: every workbook windows `Visible` property was accessible for every state of excel windows `Visible` property, the zero-visible excel windows state included. Wouldn't say what that issue of yours could derive from. I'd hope it was `Wbk` having gone out of scope...

Comment: Is `WBk` defined? If not you need to be using `ActiveWorkbook.Windows`, but I would suggest explicitly defining `WBk` instead. You can also use it without a qualifier [as suggested here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195152.aspx).

Comment: Thank you both! @Dan, yes WBk is defined as a public variable.